# "Something went wrong retrieving your Watson Visual Recognition service instance." In IBM Watson Studio

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition, watson-studio

This is my first project in IBM Watson Studio.

I have created an Image Classifier project.

I added Visual Recognition Model to my project. While adding it, I got this pop-up -

[image]

Once, added I tried to Test "The Prebuilt - General Model" but I am getting this error -

An error occurred:

Something went wrong retrieving your Watson Visual Recognition service instance. check your instance for more details.

[image]

When I click on the "check your instance for more details", it is taking me to a broken page and says:
Unfortunately, we couldn’t find the page you were looking for, but here are some helpful places to start from:

Dashboard
Catalog
Cloud Status
Documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue -

While creating the resource for Watson Studio, I was selecting the Frankfurt in the region. I deleted both the resource and service and re-added them with Dallas as the region and it worked.